# How to convert java.io.File to java.lang.Class

Tags: java

I have the following code that retrieves a list of files from a folder and in my for statement i want to compare them to see do the names match

```
        Class classFile = null;

        // Retrieve the java file 
        final File javaFolder = new File(filePath);

        // Retrieves all the class files
        List<Class> classFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        final File classFolder = new File(compileFile.getDirectoryForBin());
        classFiles = retrieveFiles.listClassFilesForFolder(classFolder);

        // compared the java files to the class files and add the correct files to the list
        for (Class currentClassFile : classFiles) {.....}
```

Im getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
at Java.OrganisingFiles.getClasses(OrganisingFiles.java:129)
```

This is because i have a list of files that cannot be cast to Class in my for loop. Does anybody know how to convert a File to a Class type or is it better to just to cast all the files as objects as `java.lang.Class` is a subclass of `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: What do you need the Class for?

Comment: Indeed, why do you need a `Class`? From your loop it looks like you'll only need to compare file names?

Comment: You can't convert a File into a Class, nor do you have any need to. If all you want is the names, just compare the names of the `File`s

Answer (score 2):

change these lines:

```
  Class classFile = null;

  List<Class> classFiles = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Class currentClassFile : classFiles) {.....}
```

to this:

```
  File classFile = null;

  List<File> classFiles = new ArrayList<>();
  for (File currentClassFile : classFiles) {.....}
```

A class file is also a File

Comment: so does this mean that if the `currentClassFile` = `Test.class` instead of writing `Test.class` you can use `currentClassFile.class` because that is what i need to do at the end of the day?

Comment: @flexinIT currentClassFile is a reference to the object that is being iterated. you can use getName() API to fetch the name. if you use getClass().getName() api you will get ClassName. Did I answer your question?

Comment: you cannot cast a File to a Class as they are incompatible hence the ClassCastException. They have to be same or one subclass of another.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take a look at [`iterateFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method from the Apache [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). There is a difference between files ending in the `.class` extension and the actual `Class` object.

The above function should allow you to get you an iterator `File` which will allow you to iterate over files having the `.class` extension.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Class` class represents the **classes, interfaces , etc during a running java application.**

**2.** Now use `listFile()` method to get all the `File Objects` and then store them in a collection like `ArrayList<String>` and compare them..

**Eg:**

```
    ArrayList<String> fnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File("d:\\Myfolder");
    File[] fArr = f.listFiles();

    for (File fN : fArr){

        fnames.add(fN.getName());

    }
```

**And now you can compare them .....**

Comment: all the files that are being returned in my method are .class files so i want to be able to, instead of hard coding classes like `Test.class` i can just use `currentClassFile`

Comment: do you have to import anything for .getInstance() as it is not appearing for me

Comment: Sorry for the typo..... Use this....    Class<File> file = File.class;
  try {
   File m = file.newInstance();
  } catch (Exception e1) {
   
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Its newInstance() Not getInstance()